# How to get the dimensions of an Icon from its handle?

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, gdi

I have a handle to the icon (HICON) and have to find out the dimensions of the icon that it represents. How do I get this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it to [`GetIconInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648070%28VS.85%29.aspx) then pass either the returned colour or mask `HBITMAP` to [`GetObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932477.aspx) to get a `BITMAP` struct that has height/width members.

Comment: It is important to note that both icons returned in `ICONINFO` must be freed using `DeleteObject` API to prevent resource leak.

Comment: My icon is 16x16 but the `BITMAP` width/height properties are saying 32x32...